# CloudFormation, networking issues with RDS and Lambda's

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-cloudformation

Been trying to get an HTTP enabled Lambda to connect to an RDS database, fetch the results and return to the caller. I'm getting all sorts of timeouts and it's driving me insane. I've never really dealt much with the infrastructure side of things so some of what I'm saying might be missing the mark.

When I tried creating a Lambda and Postgres database without any VPC's, the Lambda wasn't connecting to Postgres - timeouts there.

When I tried creating a basic VPC and put the Lambda and database inside it, the Lambda connected and got rows, but then the Lambda itself could not exit the VPC and timed out.

I'm trying to do this through CloudFormation so I don't have to worry to much about retracing my steps. So far, I have this. It should create

- a VPC
- three subnets in my region
- subnet for my database
- a security group for my functions
- a security group for my database

I think I need to make these the groups for the functions public somehow but I have no idea how that works. Can anyone put me on the right track?

```
ServerlessVPC:
  Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
  Properties:
    CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/16"
ServerlessSubnetA:
  DependsOn: ServerlessVPC
  Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
  Properties:
    VpcId:
      Ref: ServerlessVPC
    AvailabilityZone: ${self:provider.region}a
    CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/24"
ServerlessSubnetB:
  DependsOn: ServerlessVPC
  Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
  Properties:
    VpcId:
      Ref: ServerlessVPC
    AvailabilityZone: ${self:provider.region}b
    CidrBlock: "10.0.1.0/24"
ServerlessSubnetC:
  DependsOn: ServerlessVPC
  Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
  Properties:
    VpcId:
      Ref: ServerlessVPC
    AvailabilityZone: ${self:provider.region}c
    CidrBlock: "10.0.2.0/24"
ServerlessSecurityGroup:
  DependsOn: ServerlessVPC
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
    GroupDescription: SecurityGroup for Serverless Functions
    VpcId:
      Ref: ServerlessVPC
ServerlessStorageSecurityGroup:
  DependsOn: ServerlessVPC
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
    GroupDescription: Ingress for RDS Instance
    VpcId:
      Ref: ServerlessVPC
    SecurityGroupIngress:
    - IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: '5432'
      ToPort: '5432'
      SourceSecurityGroupId:
        Ref: ServerlessSecurityGroup
    - IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: '11211'
      ToPort: '11211'
      SourceSecurityGroupId:
        Ref: ServerlessSecurityGroup
    SecurityGroupEgress:
ServerlessRDSSubnetGroup:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
  Properties:
    DBSubnetGroupDescription: "RDS Subnet Group"
    SubnetIds:
    - Ref: ServerlessSubnetA
    - Ref: ServerlessSubnetB
    - Ref: ServerlessSubnetC
ServerlessRDSCluster: 
  DependsOn: ServerlessStorageSecurityGroup
  Type: "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"
  Properties: 
    DBName: ${self:custom.database_name}
    AllocatedStorage: 10
    DBInstanceClass: "db.t2.micro"
    Engine: "postgres"
    EngineVersion: "9.6.2"
    MasterUsername: ${self:custom.env.DATABASE_USER}
    MasterUserPassword: ${self:custom.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    VPCSecurityGroups:
    - "Fn::GetAtt": ServerlessStorageSecurityGroup.GroupId
    DBSubnetGroupName:
      Ref: ServerlessRDSSubnetGroup
  DeletionPolicy: "Snapshot"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your Lambda function to (a) access your RDS instance, and (b) access the outside world, then you need to put your Lambda function in your VPC, and add a NAT to your VPC for outside world access.

Do the following:

1. Put your Lambda function in a **private** subnet in your VPC.
2. Add a NAT instance or gateway in a **public** subnet.
3. Ensure your routing tables for your private subnet allow access to the RDS instance.
4. Ensure your routing tables for your private subnet direct outbound traffic to the NAT.
5. If Lambda functions support security groups, ensure your RDS instance's security group allows access to your Lambda function's security group.
   If Lambda functions do not support security groups, ensure your RDS instance's security group allows access from your private subnet's or VPC's CIDR block.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing any public subnets, nor Internet or NAT gateways, in your cloudformation template.  I don't use CloudFormation or Lambda, so it's possible there's some magic in those that makes it unnecessary, but for VPCs in general, if you want something in a private subnet to be able to talk to the outside world, you need a NAT gateway (preferably one per AZ), a public subnet for the NAT gateway to sit in, an Internet Gateway for the NAT gateway to talk through, and a default route in your private subnets via the NAT gateway.

If you look at the default VPC in your account, and trace through all the bits it has attached, you'll see the sort of structure you need to setup.